# Extract XML Data from String

Tags: c#, ajax, xml, json

I am having a input stream which is generated when I upload a file(XML Type). I need the XML data at code behind. I am having the xml data in string by using

```
 StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
 string x = stream.ReadToEnd();
```

It also contains the following data at the start of the string

```
------WebKitFormBoundary8na5dBbHc4ydfxVU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MyFile"; filename="Test 123.vfc"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

at the end of the string

```
------WebKitFormBoundary8na5dBbHc4ydfxVU--
```

This data is not required for me. Please help me in getting the right XML String.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the `Request.Files` collection?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I am sending file through jQuery Upload Plugin.

Comment: Is the XML Formatted properly, could you post the actual data that you are try to work with? Like what is x

Answer (score 0):

First you can remove the first three lines and last line from your string.

```
int n = 3;
string[] lines = str.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).Skip(n).ToArray();
string output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
output = output.Remove(str.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

In your XML string if you don't have a root node then add it like following.

```
   string xmlTxt  = "<ROOT>" + xmlString + "</ROOT>";
```

If you have a root node skip above. For a well format XML string you can just use below code

```
   XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDocument.InnerXml = xmlTxt;
```